# get SBT settings from ModuleID

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I use a `moduleID: ModuleID` for a "sibling" project to access settings keys?

I'm writing an SBT plugin for multi-module builds.

I have project A (which `dependsOn` B) and project B.
Both projects have my-own `generate` and `mybuild` tasks as settings keys.
The `mybuild` task consumes the value from `generate` - this works fine.
B doesn't depend upon anything, so B's `mybuild` only needs the key for `B:generate` and all is well.
I want A's `mybuild` to consume both `A:generate` and `B:generate` based on the fact that A `dependsOn` B in the `build.sbt` file.
The only promising key(s) I've found return the projects as `: ModuleID` instances, so is there some way to get a list of settings keys from a `ModuleID`?

... or should I be doing this another way?

## Solution (Kind of)

Whth [@himos help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048928/#54051997) this ...

```
(myTaskKey in myConfig) := {
    loadedBuild.value.allProjectRefs.find(_._1 == thisProjectRef.value).map(_._2) match {
        case Some(myCurrentProject) =>
            if (myCurrentProject.dependencies.nonEmpty)
                sys.error {
                    myCurrentProject.dependencies
                        .map {
                            myDependsOnProject: ClasspathDep[ProjectRef] =>
                                (myDependsOnProject.project / myConfig / myTaskKey).value
                                // https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with
                        }
                        .foldLeft("mine.dependencies:")(_ + "\n\t" + _)
                }
    }
}
```

... sort of works.
It causes an error that implies I've accessed the correct object, even if the SBT macros don't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ModuleID that you mention relates to dependency management, not sub projects.
For taking sub project setting/task keys project scope can be used:

```
(generate in A).value
(generate in B).value
```

More comprehensive example:

```
name := "A"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.5"

val generate = TaskKey[String]("generate")
val myBuild = TaskKey[String]("myBuild")

val a = (project in file(".")).settings(Seq(
  generate := "A_generate"
))
val b = (project in file("proj_b")).settings(Seq(
 generate := "B_generate",
 myBuild := (generate in a).value + "_" + generate.value
)).dependsOn(a)
```

Sbt console output:

```
sbt:A> show b/myBuild
[info] A_generate_B_generate
```

Comment: Yeah ... almost. I'm not working in the `.sbt` file, I'm trying to write an auto-plugin that doesn't require any special *me too* syntax. Is there some way (in an auto-plugin) to query for projects that have been attached with `dependsOn()`?

Comment: This should work from any place: `loadedBuild.value.allProjectRefs.find(_._1.project == projectID.value.name).get._2.dependencies`

Comment: Yes! ... I'm now getting an `Illegal dynamic reference: ...` when trying to access the `(project / config / taskKey).value` which means ... I have access to the projects. Thank you